# Object property shows property/method in VSCode,why are they different?

Tags: javascript, typescript

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Aca.png)

```
const obj = {
  name1: function name() {
    console.log('name1')
  },
  name2: function () {
    console.log('name2')
  },
  name3() {
    console.log('name3')
  },
}
```

name1 shows property
name2 shows property
but name3 shows method

how does it works?

Comment: VSCode makes a difference based on how the method is defined in the object literal. When it meets a key name and `:`, the property is considered as a property, when VSCode meets [a method shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#syntax), it's considered as a method.

Comment: Hi and welcome, try to share you code from pic1 as TEXT not as an image, you can use code fences for that. It is much nicer to read.

Answer (score 0):

`name1` and `name2` are properties of the object. Altough they are functions they are still properties, while `name3` **is** a function on the object

Comment: Nope, they all are properties of the object.

Comment: thanks for the answer. `name3` is an ES6 object property shorthand of `name2` ,so I believe they should have the same display results.